# Unable to bind Http Form data to HashMap collection

Tags: grails

I am trying to post form data as

> "student.id=1&courses[10].course.id=10"

The command object classes we are trying to bind are as below ...

```
class StudentEnrollmentCmd {
    Student student
    Map<String,CourseCmd> courses;
}

class CourseCmd {
    CourseDomain course
}

class CourseDomain {
    Long id
}
```

was hoping that it will bind to

> "StudentEnrollmentCmd -> courses -> course.id"

which seems to work in grails 2.2.4 but fails in 3.3.7 with the following exception

> No such property: course.id for class: student.CourseCmd

Here is the test case which illustrates the problem

```
void 'databinding from request parameters'() {
        given:
        // request with simple formdata: student.id=1&courses[10].course.id=10
        MockHttpServletRequest request = buildMockRequestWithParams('POST',['student.id':'1','courses[10].course.id':'10']);
        DataBindingSource source = bindingSourceCreator.createDataBindingSource(null,null,request);

        // databinder & command object
        def binder = new SimpleDataBinder()
        def obj = new StudentEnrollmentCmd()

        when:
        binder.bind(obj,source)

        then:
        // this should not throw an exception, but throws an exception
        MissingPropertyException ex = thrown()
        System.out.println ( "Exception again:" + ex.message );

        // the following should work, but does not work
        obj.student.id == 1
        obj.courses['10'].course.id == 10
    }
```

Here is the link to full spec... https://github.com/swzaidi/sample/blob/master/grails3.3.7/src/test/groovy/student/DataBindingSpec.groovy

Looking for some help on how to pass the form data so that it binds to above command objects properly.

Comment: Why is it that you want to use the lazy map approach in recent versions of Grails?

Comment: We are trying to upgrade from grails 2.2.4 over to grails 3.37 and the lazymap is in existing code. Could you recommend an approach?

Comment: "Could you recommend an approach?" - I would recommend not using the lazy map.  https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2d9e4b30346697358a53f567aed8fb0b3f3598ea/grails-databinding/src/test/groovy/grails/databinding/CollectionBindingSpec.groovy#L132-L143

Comment: Made the changes as per your recommendation, getting the same error as earlier.

Comment: Hi Jeff, please look at the spec https://github.com/swzaidi/sample/blob/master/grails3.3.7/src/test/groovy/student/DataBindingSpec.groovy, we are passing simple formdata "student.id=1&courses[10].course.id=10" & bind to "StudentEnrollmentCmd -> courses -> course.id" i was hoping that the first testcase should work..

Comment: There are a number of things in that code which demonstrates a misunderstanding of how the data binder works.  There is more there than is practical to address as a StackOverflow question, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the response. I have edited the original question. Please take a look and let us know your recommendation on how to get the form data to command object binding to work.

Comment: "Please take a look and let us know your recommendation..." - I am sorry.  I don't think I can be of any help.  Best of luck!